# LibreOffice saves slow and pauses on first save with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: libreoffice

I'm experiencing some strange behavior with Libre Office on Ubuntu 14.04.  This applies to both the version bundled with 14.04, and the latest version from the Libre Office website.

When I open Libre Office Writer and start working on a brand-new document and save it, the first save takes a really long time and the window grays out.  After a while the save finishes and the window starts responding again.  But when I continue typing the document, it pauses a second or so for every few words.

If I close Libre Office then open it again and open the document I saved before and start working on it, it saves normally and works normally.  This issue only occurs when saving a document for the first time.